# What is the suggested openssl command to generate EC Key and CSR compatible with Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, hyperledger-fabric

We have used openssl to generate CSRs (certificate signing request) as follows.

- Step1: generate ECPARAM.pem file

`openssl genpkey -genparam -algorithm ec -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:P-384 -out ECPARAM.pem`

- Step2: generate privateKey and CSR:

`openssl req -newkey ec:ECPARAM.pem -keyout PRIVATEKEY.key -out MYCSR.csr`

A new **peer** certificate is issued and signed from the corresponding CA out of the CSR listed above.

When **peer** is started, outputs the following error:

> 2020-11-22 22:28:14.635 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo

I suppose the problem is related to the **format** of the EC Key generated by openssl?
Below a sample of the private key that is causing the error:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBEzBOBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wQTApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQIQtU4Ouojj6MCAggA
MAwGCCqGSIb3DQIJBQAwFAYIKoZIhvcNAwcECC+I/OCseSp1BIHAeSmeCRFHlKzO
Hw1RK5wQi8hSulmi4HZjMJC6rofFFwGqgbBCKo9dBbJXYYsYc1AukAKyo+w6W4a3
0BpTGNAP4/eVB0dsFm7oHpJiZ2jmvgsYTHtchCciCastVph7zOfyggobPfEO97cU
iwtq3v1R5yGA1ic/2vIqtSxynnGzrTiUnwnrvPC0hXMYiDHmYfN66BK898bfcaXp
MqnBFfOQSRAtVzN71hiBWjGjVm3Y4e/vDYse/GLsseDnPK9fw3XA
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

After comparing with keys generated by **cryptogen** tool, they have different header line and length:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGkAgEBBDBXq+IIvjEQITYhxIui0ivOY/eVH1Ql8R5wXowiPSdLwZbsIrk6LHjw
jB8D9oqOW4agBwYFK4EEACKhZANiAASNt3bW+GicurJPRaj+oaY/xjaD9Mf/ic4i
3fdgI7wQnvXnGLX0Lf5ygd5ZyyhPW2Tvj7FdOW4vzaqZqSHkaG37GaP6JxpmR3/l
HuF+tncpsjUY7SXTCfzIysxvod9gN9g=
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Any suggestion to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Fabric does not support encrypted keys.  When generating the private keys using openssl, you should be able to pass the `-nocrypt` option to generate unencrypted keys or you can convert encrypted keys to unencrypted keys:

`openssl ec -in PRIVATEKEY.key -out PK_UNENCRYPPTED.pem`

Comment: Why the -1 here?