# KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo running hyperledger client

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am running a hyperledger fabric v1.4 cluster. I created all my certificates using openSSL with this command:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey ec -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:prime256v1 -keyout ecdsa.key -out mycert.crt -subj "/C=US/ST=STATE/L=CITY/O=Company/OU=admin/CN=admin.company.com"
```

Changing OU and CN for each, my peers are running, my orderers are running, my orderers have consensus, and now I want to create a channel from a client.

I'm using fabric-tools 1.4.11 image with these env variables for my client:

```
GOPATH=/var/hyperledger
CORE_PEER_ID=cli
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED="true"
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE="[/var/hyperledger/peer/msp/tlsintermediatecerts/intermediate.crt,/var/hyperledger/peer/msp/tlscacerts/ca.crt]"
CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED="true"
CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/peer/tls/cert.pem
CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE=/var/hyperledger/peer/tls/key.pem
CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES="[/var/hyperledger/peer/msp/tlsintermediatecerts/intermediate.crt,/var/hyperledger/peer/msp/tlscacerts/ca.crt]"
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/peer/msp
FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/peer
FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC="grpc=debug:info"
```

But when I try to create a channel I get this error:

```
2021-03-25 18:59:05.672 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /var/hyperledger/peer/msp: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo
```

This is the command I'm using:

```
peer channel create -o "orderer1.xxxx.eastus.aksapp.io" -c "mychannel" -f ./channel.tx --tls --cafile "/var/hyperledger/peer/tls/chain.crt" --clientauth --certfile /var/hyperledger/peer/tls/admintls.crt --keyfile /var/hyperledger/peer/tls/admintls.key
```

This is my MSP structure:

```
+ /var/hyperledger/peer
  + msp
    + admincerts > admin.crt
    + cacerts > ca.crt
    + intermediatecerts > intermediate.crt
    + tlscacerts > ca.crt
    + tlsintermediatecerts > intermediate.crt
    + signcerts > admin.crt
    + keystore > admin.key
  + tls
    admintls.crt
    admintls.key
    ca.crt
    intermediate.crt
    chain.crt
```

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961096/what-is-the-suggested-openssl-command-to-generate-ec-key-and-csr-compatible-with) but my keys are unencrypted like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I also double checked that all my certs and keys in the msp where alone in their folders, I have tried enabling and disabling mutual TLS in the orderers, doing chmod -R 777 in the msp folder, changing all names to .crt or .pem, and checked go version, with no luck.

My certificates don't have these attributes: hf.EnrollmentID, hf.Type and hf.Affiliation, but I guess those aren't necesary as the peers and orderers are running, or maybe is that the problem?

Thanks any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, I was using peer admin certificates instead of orderer admin certificates and I didn't added a config.yaml with node OUs. so I changed the certificates to the orderer admin and the error dissapeared.

**UPDATE:**

Actually the problem was that I placed the wrong key file in the keystore folder, thats why they didn't match.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the problem was that I was missing a file in the MSP folder. Since I am using Fabric 2.2 with [Organizational Units](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/msp.html#organizational-units) the file tree that you should consider (and check everything is there) is this:

```
/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
  - cacerts
    - name-related-to-your-ca.pem
  - IssuerPublicKey
  - signcerts
    - cert.pem
  - IssuerRevocationPublicKey
  - keystore
    - <secret_string>_sk
  - user
  - config.yaml

/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
  - cacerts
  - IssuerPublicKey
  - signcerts
    - cert.pem
  - IssuerRevocationPublicKey
  - keystore
    - <secret_string>_sk
  - server.key
  - user
  - ca.crt
  - tlscacerts
    - tls-name-related-to-your-ca.pem
  - server.crt
```