# Error installling chaincode on the network

Tags: installation, hyperledger-fabric, chaincode

I get the following error when I try to install chaincode

```
VirtualBox:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ peer lifecycle chaincode install GameEX.tar.gz --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 
2021-08-12 16:01:53.066 IST [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /home/raju/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo
```

The code was written in java and compiled fine. Using test-network to deploy chaincode the network was running

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo running hyperledger client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66807986/keymaterial-not-found-in-signingidentityinfo-running-hyperledger-client)